# there is a page ($9\times 9$) how many different rectangles can you draw with odd area

Tags: discrete-mathematics

there is a page ($9\times 9$) how many different rectangles can you draw with odd area?

rectangles are different if they are different on size and place.

for example if a rectangle is $15$ squares, its area is odd. 
if a rectangle is $12$ squares, its area is even.

I have no idea how to approach this question so I can't give my answer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the area has to be odd, the length and breadth both have to be odd. Hence, we count the number of rectangles by first choosing a row and a column ($10 \cdot 10$ ways to do this), and then choosing another row and column which are at an odd distance from the chosen one ($5 \cdot 5$ ways to do this). But we have counted each rectangle four times -- by the first row/column and then again by the second row/column -- so we divide by 4 to get our final answer: $1/4 \cdot 10 \cdot 10 \cdot 5 \cdot 5 = 625$.

Comment: The problem asks us to count rectangles with an odd area. Since the area is equal to the product of the length and the breadth, if any one of these is even, the area will also be even. Thus both the length and breadth have to be odd.

Comment: i skipped it...

Comment: 1 more doubt here you divide by 2 but a rectangle of same odd area can be vertical or horizontal.

Comment: The question states that rectangles are different if they have different sizes or different places. I assume that a $3 \times 5$ rectangle is not the same as a $5 \times 3$ rectangle.

Comment: ya exactly so where are they counted twice??

Comment: I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

the number of squares with equal dimensions is $81$. so if number of squares is odd then the rectangle has an odd area.  the total rectangles are given by ${10 \choose 2}.{10 \choose 2}=2025$  . you have rectangles now you just need to select two lines which are odd distances apart from each other . and its done. hope its clear.